# How do I place <a>-block into right-bottom angle of current <div>?

Tags: css, html

I have a `<div>` with news and I need to place Author into right-bottom corner.

I tried to use

```
<a href="..." style="position: relative; right: 0; bottom: 0;">Autnor name</a>
```

but it isn't working.

I have not more ideas about it. 
Thanks

Comment: A fiddle link will be very helpful. Please provide a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three position types at play here: static, relative, and absolute.

All elements default to static.

Absolute elements will be positioned relative to their closest parent that isn't statically positioned.  This is why people will often position an element as "relative" without intending to change its position.

So, in this case, `#b` is positioned relative to the body (well the document, technically).

```
<body>
  <div id="a">
    <div id="b" style="position: absolute"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

In this case, `#b` is positioned relative to `#a`.

```
<body>
  <div id="a" style="position: relative">
    <div id="b" style="position: absolute"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

In your case, you can position it like this:

```
<article style="position: relative">
  <a href="..." style="position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0;">The Author</a>
</article>
```

Answer (score 2):

just say that your  divs have the class book:

```
<div class=book style="position: relative; width: 200px; height: 120px;background:#ccc; margin-bottom:20px; display:block;">

    <a href="..." style="position: absolute; right: 0; bottom: 0;">Autnor name</a>
</div>
```

it is very important to make the parent relative when you use position absolute

demo:http://jsfiddle.net/9d8Mh/